# Lyx beamer pdf without sub-slides

Tags: beamer, lyx, pdf

Hey I do presentation in Lyx in which I have a lot of sub-slides i.e. one things appear on the slide after another thing.  Is it possible to somehow generate two pdf files, one of which has all the sub-slides and the other is such a simplified version in which everything appears at once?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the "simplified version", go to Document > Settings and in the "Custom:" field of "Class Options" put "handout". Press "OK".

For more information, please see Help > Specific Manuals > Beamer Presentations